# Из 1000 сделать 1.000 (format)

Tags: python, format

Python, из 1000 сделать 1.000 (format).
Есть переменные, к примеру

```
a = 1000
b = 2500
c = 5213234
```

Нужно вывести

> ```
> a = 1.000
> b = 2.500
> c = 5.213.234
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте классный модуль [humanize](https://github.com/jmoiron/humanize) (`pip install humanize`)

```
import humanize

print(humanize.intcomma(1000))     # '1,000'
print(humanize.intcomma(2500))     # '2,500'
print(humanize.intcomma(5213234))  # '5,213,234'

# Разделители в виде точки лучше не делать, если используются вещественные числа
c = humanize.intcomma(5213234)
print(c.replace(',', '.'))         # '5.213.234'
```

Comment: действительно классный модуль! Я в свое время сам реализовывал некоторые из его функций... если бы знал о его существовании мог бы сэкономить время

Answer (score 4):

```
'{:,d}'.format(1000)
# 1,000

'{:,d}'.format(5213234)
# 5,213,234

'{:,d}'.format(2500).replace(',', '.')
# 2.500
```

Comment: Клевое форматирование! Удобно

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_formatted(num):
    print(format(num, ",d").replace(",","."))
```

Тест:

```
print_formatted(123456898)
```

Результат:

> 123.456.898